# Controlling volume via javascript with an input slider?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, volume

I adapted this from code I found that showed how to control volume in a video with an input slider. I know I'm not doing this right (the problems seem to lie in the audio tag) but I'm not sure how to go on.

```
<audio id="song" autoplay>
  <source src="http://beemp3s.org/index.php?q=Super-Mario-Theme.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
<div id="volume-controls">
    <input type="range" id="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" />
</div>
```

The script:

```
$('#volume').on('change', function() {
    $('#song').prop("volume", this.value);
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsKVn). I simply just want to control the volume, nothing too fancy.

Comment: You know you're not referencing an audio file? Try copy pasting that URL in the browser, and it does not return any audio, and that's why it's not working.

Comment: Um, your code works fine. The problem is with linking to mp3 file that's actually a html file. Here's fiddle with actual mp3:  http://jsfiddle.net/rh8TZ/

Comment: @eithedog thanks a lot! I'm kind of sleep deprived and just grabbed the first line that said 'mp3' from a beemp3 embedded code.